Setting Faketime in Freeradius Server
I'm trying to set "fake time" in Freeradius sever to accept the expired certificate.
I'm searching for freeradius.service or radius.service file to edit and add ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/faketime '2022-01-01 00:00:00' /usr/sbin/radiusd -X this line so that it can accept the older certificate.But I'm unable to find neither of both files to edit.
Any idea where does this file are located or is there any other way to set faketime to freeradius server ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
